# Create and use a function registry in F#

Tags: f#

I am using the current pattern of code a lot in a program I am currently writing:

```
let test_titles = ["a_fault"; "b_fault"; "c_fault"]
let tests: (unit -> 'component option) list = [a_fault; b_fault; c_fault]
let test_registry = List.zip test_titles tests
let apply_test (title, test) = test () |> Option.map (fun s -> (title, s))
let result: (string * 'component) option = test_registry |> List.tryPick apply_test
```

to have a test registry of tests that identify faulty components and the error type which happens to be the same name as the name of the function.

1. Is there a better way to create this test_registry, preferably without me writing the test names manually (dynamically getting the function name)?
2. Generally, is this idiomatic F#?

**Edit**: The code had a mistake in the last line. The result is computed using `test_registry` rather than `tests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the need to write the name of the test explicitly in the code (as a string) would be to use quotations. Instead of creating a list of functions and a list of strings, you can create a list of "quoted" function values. Then you can write code that processes the quotations and gives you everything you need.

I assume that your tests look roughly as below (functions taking unit and returning some value as a result). The list would be constructed as follows:

```
let test_a () = Some 32
let test_b () = None
let tests = [ <@ test_a @>; <@ test_b @> ]
```

Then you can write code like this to get information about test:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let getInfo (e:Expr<unit -> 'R>) = // '
  match e.Raw with 
  // This expects that the quotation contains a reference to a global
  // function (in some module) that takes unit as the parameter
  | Lambda(a, Call(_, m, _)) -> 
      // Return a tuple containing a name of the test (string) and
      // a function that invokes it (note that the invocation will be 
      // a bit slow as we use reflection here)
      m.Name, (fun () -> m.Invoke(null, [| |]) :?> 'R) // ' (*)
  // Ohter quotations will cause an exception
  | _ -> failwith "unexpected quotation"
```

Here is an example how you would use that:

```
let e = <@ test_a @>    
let s, f = getInfo e // gives 'string * (unit -> int option)

// Your original code could be written like this:
tests |> List.map getInfo |> List.tryPick (fun (title, test) ->
  test () |> Option.map (fun s -> (title, s)))
```

Alternatively you could modify the line `(*)` to produce a function that returns the name of the test and the result, which removes the need for `Option.map`:

```
// An alternative version of the marked line in the 'getInfo' function
(fun () -> m.Name, m.Invoke(null, [| |]) :?> 'R) // ' (*)

// Then you can write just:
tests |> List.map getInfo |> List.tryPick (fun test -> test())
```

Comment: Thanks. It tool me a while to understand, but I got it working. For those checking the answer in future, the part after 'Alternatively' is not currently valid given that I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

This seems not bad, but another option to consider is to have the tests know their own names.  Right now you have (I infer)

```
type Test<'comp> = unit -> 'comp option
```

and you could have instead

```
type Test<'comp> = unit -> string * 'comp option
```

where the string is the name.

I don't have a good sense of your 'big picture' to offer other advice or know whether this makes sense.

Just throwing it out there, if the tests are part of some module `M`, you could use the `(?)` operator cleverly so that e.g. `M?foo` has access to both the test function and its name.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the duplication, either in the sense of `let test1(x) = Some("test1",x)` or having them in external lists as in the question.
The idea of `?` operator looks good to me. Do you mean that it should be defined to return both the string and the actual function? If so, how? I have split this in a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178829/f-dynamic-operator-giving-access-both-to-function-and-function-name