# F# dynamic operator giving access both to function and function name

Tags: dynamic, f#

Given a number of functions `test1`, `test2`, ... belonging to a module:

```
module Checks =
    let test1 x = ...
    let test2 x = ...
    ...
```

how can the (?) operator be used to give access to both the function name and the function itself? The result should look like:

```
let name, func = Checks?test1
assert(name = "test1")
assert(func(x) = Checks.test1(x)) //whatever x is (test1 is known to be pure)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code that shows off some of this.  I use `D` as the 'dynamic' access of the `Checks` module plus function name.

```
module Checks = 
    let test1(x) = printfn "test1 %d" x
    let test2(x,y) = printfn "test2 %s %d" x y

type MyDynamic() = class end
let D = new MyDynamic()
let (?) (md:MyDynamic) fname : (string * ('a -> 'r)) =
    let a = md.GetType().Assembly
    let t = a.GetType("Program+Checks")
    let m = t.GetMethod(fname)
    let f arg = 
        let at = arg.GetType()
        let fsharpArgs = 
            if at.IsGenericType && at.GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName.StartsWith("System.Tuple`") then
                Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(arg)
            else
                [| box arg |]
        unbox(m.Invoke(null, fsharpArgs))
    fname, f

let Main() =
    let x = 42
    let s = "foo"
    let name, func = D?test1 
    assert(name = "test1") 
    assert(func(x) = Checks.test1(x))

    let name, func = D?test2
    assert(name = "test2") 
    assert(func(s,x) = Checks.test2(s,x))

    System.Console.ReadKey()

Main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the `?` operator to access functions in a module, because the construct `Checks?test1` is not syntactically correct (this would be translated to `(?) Checks "test"` and you cannot use module names as values).

However, it should be possible to do this for members of a type using an instance of the object (e.g. `obj?test`). Alternatively you could write a "fake" object instance (that knows the name of the module). The implementation of `?` would then look for the module and search static members in the module.

The simplest implementation (of the first case) would look like this:

```
let (?) obj s = 
  let memb = obj.GetType().GetMethod(s)
  // Return name and a function that runs the method
  s, (fun args -> memb.Invoke(obj, args))

// Type that contains tests as members    
type Check() = 
  member x.test1 () = 32

// We need to create instance in order to use '?'
let ch = Check()
let s,f = ch?test1

// Function 'f' takes array of objects as an argument and
// returns object, so the call is not as elegant as it could be
let n = ((f [| |]) :?> int)
```

You could also add some wrapping to make the function 'f' a little bit nicer, but I hope this demonstrates the idea. Unfortunately, this cannot work for modules.